# UltraHook doesn't allow me to set subdomain

Tags: ruby

Currently i am trying to setup a callback url on localhost with [UltraHook](http://www.ultrahook.com/). But whenever i try to configure the subdomain and localhost target it says:

```
Error: Subdomain can only contain alphanumeric characters and hyphen (-)
```

My code looks as following:

```
$ ultrahook -k mysecretAPIKEY stripe.mysecretname.ultrahook.com mydev.dev
```

Notice that the API-key can have uppercase and lowercase values. while the subdomain can't.

Comment: You have to specify just a subdomain, e.g. `stripe`, not a full domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.ultrahook.com/faq):

> #### How do I use the UltraHook client?
>
> There are two required parameters:
> source hostname and destination. An optional API key can be provided:
>
> ```
> $ ultrahook [-k <key>] <subdomain> <destination>
> ```

where `<subdomain>` is just the subdomain, e.g. `stripe`.

You have to write:

```
$ ultrahook -k mysecretAPIKEY stripe mydev.dev
```